# Symfony 3 quick ways to build forms and validations

Tags: php, forms, symfony

While symfony does a lot of great things, I feel like the some parts could easily be generated from a script, like

- form builder: having to `->add()` each and every line manually
- getting data from post submits: `$name_of_var = $request['name_of_var']->getData()`
- setting each variable after a submit: `$class_name->setNameOfVar($name_of_var);`

with a database with, say, 20 fields, it's quite a lot of repetitive work. So I'd think there must be an easy way to generate some kind of "default" PHP-Form-Builder with all lines and probably class guessing, etc. So the result would be some kind of default PHP-Form-Builder-Code with - in this case - 20 `->add()` lines.

Does this exist or do I oversee something obvious?

Comment: In the Symfony cookbook there should be a "CRUD" generator, it's a few command lines.  First they introspect the database, make the orm maps, then you can generate the crud, sorry I don't have time to provide links.

Comment: I'm puzzled by your second two points.  In most cases, the form takes care of all the request - data mapping.

Comment: @AaronBelchamber docs are unclear about the output. Sorry, I do not have time to test it - and moreover - i want to find the "best practice" with this stack question.

Comment: @Cerad yep, but what about further validation that can't be handled with the default classes?

Comment: @Petermeir I'm sure your comment means something but I have no idea what.  You can add additional validation as you create the form.  And if you really need to do something special then no crud generator in the world will be able to figure it out.

Comment: @Cerad will test it and might answer the question myself. Thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate a form

```
s doctrine:generate:form bundle:file
```

and in the controller you can persist all your class

```
 $form = $this->createForm(fileType::class,$file );


        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() ) {

            $em->persist( $file);
            $em->flush();

        }
```

and just starts the form in twig page

i guess thats the easiest way

Comment: thanks, I found that but the docs are unclear. Does it output the PHP code or - and this is my guess - does it output the HTML5 Form. The former would be great and the correct answer, the latter is suboptimal as one might want to reuse the form builder.

Comment: it output the .twig.html Form     return $this->render('MyBundle:file.html.twig',array(
            'form'=>$form->createView(),)